# convert the output into a vector

Tags: r, function, bioinformatics

this code prints two arrays called RandomArraySeq 1, and RandomArraySeq 2, with random sequences of 5 lengths, right?

```
generateNTarrays <- function(num_arrays = 5, array_length = 5,
                         allowed_characters = c('A', 'T', 'C', 'G'), seed=123) {
arrays <- replicate(num_arrays, sample(allowed_characters, array_length, replace = TRUE), simplify = F)
return(arrays)
}

print_arrays <- function(arrays) {
num_arrays <- length(arrays)
for (i in 1:num_arrays) {
cat(paste("RandomArraySeq", i, ":", paste(arrays[[i]], collapse = ""), "\n"))
  }
}

# Call the functions outside of the definition
     generated_arrays <- generateNTarrays(2,5)
     print_arrays(generated_arrays)
```

outputs in the console appear as:

> RandomArraySeq 1 : CCTGA
> RandomArraySeq 2 : AGGAA

Now I want have output as objects, what I mean is having two objects of  `RandomArraySeq 1` and `RandomArraySeq 2` whose values are those random sequences.
of course I am talking about R programming language as you probably already noticed.

I tried using loops, but I could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a list whose members are character sequences, have the function `generateNTarrays` return a named vector. This also simplifies the print code.

Note that `seed` is not used in the function, like it wasn't in your original code.

```r
generateNTarrays <- function(num_arrays = 5, array_length = 5,
                             allowed_characters = c('A', 'T', 'C', 'G'), seed=123) {
  arrays <- replicate(num_arrays, sample(allowed_characters, array_length, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)
  arrays <- sapply(arrays, paste, collapse = "")
  arrays_names <- sprintf("RandomArraySeq_%d", seq_along(arrays))
  setNames(arrays, arrays_names)
}

print_arrays <- function(arrays) {
  for (i in seq_along(arrays)) {
    cat(names(arrays)[i], ":", arrays[i], "\n")
  }
}

# Call the functions outside of the definition
generated_arrays <- generateNTarrays(2,5)
generated_arrays
#> RandomArraySeq_1 RandomArraySeq_2 
#>          "ACCCA"          "TTTTC"

print_arrays(generated_arrays)
#> RandomArraySeq_1 : ACCCA 
#> RandomArraySeq_2 : TTTTC
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

The following function is equivalent to the function above but uses R's native pipe operator introduced in R 4.1.

```
generateNTarrays <- function(num_arrays = 5, array_length = 5,
                             allowed_characters = c('A', 'T', 'C', 'G'), seed=123) {
  # output vector is a named vector
  arrays_names <- sprintf("RandomArraySeq_%d", seq_len(num_arrays))
  # create the vector and assign its names before returning to caller
  num_arrays |>
    replicate(sample(allowed_characters, array_length, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE) |> 
    sapply(paste, collapse = "") |>
    setNames(arrays_names)
}
```